# Accidently deleted libstdc++.so.6 Ubuntu

Tags: linux

In the process of creating symbolic links, stupidly overusing sudo and not understanding things, I have gone ahead and deleted libstdc++.so.6 from:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
which i think was linking to 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16 
which too I deleted (don't ask why...)

So now i can't run most programs (e.g. aptitude, apt-get) as they give the error: 
error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So how do I get around this problem? Very amateur linux user so please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Cheers

EDIT:

Thanks guys! I ended up getting the libstdc++.so.6.0.16 file from a friends computer and creating a file libstdc++.so.6 file linked to that. Also had to make sure to change permissions for libstdc++.so.6.0.16 to 644 ( -rw-r--r-- ). Guessing it would have been a similar thing if I had put in the live cd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your installation cd. Boot the cd in the "Try Ubuntu" mode and copy the missing files from the cd to your harddrive.

Comment: you may need to mount the hard drive yourself